# Finding a phrase within a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to check if the phrase "purple cow" exists within a string. There must be at least one space or punctuation mark between "purple" and "cow"; "purplecow" is not acceptable. I tried the following program but got an error message.

```
import string

def findPC(string):

    strLower = string.lower()

    # remove 'purplecow' in strLower
    strLowerB = strLower.replace('purplecow', '')
    print(strLowerB)

    strList = list(strLowerB)
    print(strList)

    # remove punctuation in strLowerB
    punct = string.punctuation()
    for char in strList:
        if char in punct:
            strList.replace(char, '')

    # remove spaces in strLowerB
    strLower.replace(' ', '')
    print(strLower)

    # look for 'purplecow' in strLowerB
    return 'purplecow' in string


print(findPC('The purple cow is soft and cuddly. purplecow. Purple^&*(^&$cow.'))
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python36/findPC.py",
line 28, in <module>
    print(findPC('The purple cow is soft and cuddly. purplecow. Purple^&*(^&$cow.'))   File "C:/Python36/findPC.py", line 15, in
findPC
    punct = string.punctuation() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
```

Comment: "Got an error message" is not a problem description. Please specify the exact error message in your post

Comment: what error message did you get? can you include it in the post?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use regex, which would've done the job much more easily?

Comment: Would "purplefoo barcow" satisfy "at least one space between purple and cow"?

Comment: This is the error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python36/findPC.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(findPC('The purple cow is soft and cuddly. purplecow. Purple^&*(^&$cow.'))
  File "C:/Python36/findPC.py", line 15, in findPC
    punct = string.punctuation()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'

Comment: Now, you may or may not have realised this, but your function uses the name `string` for the variable being passed. you `import string` but in the function scope, that module name is being overwritten in local scope.

Comment: "purplefoo barcow" would not be accepted because only spaces or punctuation are allowed between "purple" and "cow". "purple^(%*(%*cow" would be accepted.

Comment: In this case, more elegant solutions using regex aside, the only problem seems t be the name shadowing. Voting to close for simply typo.

Comment: I just changed the parameter being passed to "a", and I get the same error message.

Comment: @HongraeCho: `string.punctuation` is a "String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale" according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) — it's not a callable like a function.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code stems from your use of `string` in two places, where they mean different things. I've edited your code somewhat to make it work the way you intended.

```
import string

def findPC(input_string):

    strLower = input_string.lower()

    # remove 'purplecow' in strLower
    strLowerB = strLower.replace('purplecow', '')
    print(strLowerB)

    # remove punctuation in strLowerB
    punct = string.punctuation
    for char in punct:
      strLowerB = strLowerB.replace(char, '')

    # remove spaces in strLowerB
    strLowerB.replace(' ', '')
    print(strLowerB)

    # look for 'purplecow' in strLowerB
    return 'purplecow' in strLowerB


print(findPC('The purple cow is soft and cuddly. purplecow. Purple^&*(^&$cow.'))
```

Comment: That is not the only issue. You've silently corrected the fact that `string.punctuation` isn't callable and removed the offending converting it into a list line. However, you still do a bunch of operations on various names and in the end all of this is ignored for `return ... in input_string`.

Comment: This also matches `"p u r p l e c o w"`

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions

```
import re

# 'at least space or punctuation mark` - depends on that is treated a punctuation mark. I've put comma and hyphen, you can extend the list
r = r'purple[\s\,\-]+cow' 
s = 'The purple cow is soft and cuddly. purplecow.Purple^&*(^&$cow.'

print('Found' if re.search(r, s) else 'Not found')
```

Comment: Of course, `re.search` does not really tell much about `purplecow` or that final variant. also, puctuatios is more than just `,` and `-`.

Comment: Still, the general approach is sound, but I'd suggest using just `purple\W+cow`.

Comment: @tobias_k I didnt get what you mean under telling much on `purplecow`. The OP requires **at least one space or punctuation** and my regex satisfies it. Extending the list of punctuation signs can be unlimited, dont see the point to stop at, so what is the reason of enlarging it in example?

Comment: @tobias_k agree on `\W+`, it is really reasonable approach, but a little bit implicit

Comment: I meant that while you show that your regex finds a purple cow in that string, we do not know whether it matches the "purple cow", the "purplecow", or really any other part of that string. A string that does _not_ match would be a good addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Regex, you can implement this with a Regex of the form  `` purple[ .,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+cow `` which matches what you want.

NB: the characters in the square brackets are what you are considering 'punctuation'. The `+` means you are matching *one or more* of the characters in those square brackets in a row.

This is implemented in Python like so:

```
import re
re.search(r"purple[ .,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+cow", string)
```

`re.search(pattern, string)` will give you a `re.Match` object containing more information about the match (or a `None` if there is no matches), but if you just want a `true/false` value indicating whether the Regex is matched or not, you can implement this like so:

```
matched = not re.search(pattern, string) == None
```

This means you could, therefore, implement your code like this:

```
import re
def findPC(s):
    return not re.search(r"purple[ .,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+cow", s) == None
```

You can test Regexes, such as this one for example, on websites like this: https://regexr.com/463uk.

Edit: improved Regex

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106933 Just replace the "purple.+cow" with this regex

Comment: Thanks for fixing my regex, people @tobias_k

Answer (score 1):

What about using a regex to change punctuation marks with spaces and then another regex to remove extra spaces:

```py
import re
string =re.sub("[.!?\\-,]"," ",string)
string= re.sub("\s+"," ",string)
```

Then you can just us `in` :

```py
"purple cow" in string
```

so the final function becomes:

```py
def has_purple_cow(string):
    import re
    string =re.sub("[.!?\\-,]"," ",string)
    string= re.sub("\s+"," ",string)
    return "purple cow" in string
```